# Find all posts you upvoted on all the sites

Tags: feature-request, voting, network-profile

Just like you could find posts you upvoted on a particular site:

```
http://xxx.stackexchange.com/users/{you}?tab=votes
```

it'd be nice to have a feature to see all the posts you upvoted on all the sites. Probably in stackexchange site:

```
http://stackexchange.com/users/{you}?tab=votes
```

Comment: If you are active on more than a few sites this would generate a lot of data. I'm not sure of the value of just dumping this on the user - even if they asked for it. What's your rationale for this request (other than "it'd be nice")?

Comment: @ChrisF My rationale was that sometimes I want to find out the post I upvoted but I don't remember which site exactly did I upvoted it on, or don't even remember the post itself, just that I upvoted something recently and I don't know what or where. In that situation a combined list would be very useful. 

Can you expand on how lot of data would be unwanted?

Comment: Large data sets might be unwanted because of the bandwidth they consume and the time it takes to render. I know both of these can be minimised, but that takes development effort that could be expended elsewhere. I'm not saying that this is a bad idea in and of itself, but that you have to show a real benefit from having this feature.